# Order by a calculated column in GAE datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can i make a query with results sorted by a calculated column? (I can not pre calculate the result in other column to do the sorting!)

**Example:**

In a RDBMS tables like that:

```
TABLE products(
    product_id  INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    price       DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
    qty         INTEGER      NOT NULL,
);
```

I can perform this query:

```
SELECT   product_id, (price * qty * {{current_tax}}) AS custom_calc
FROM     products
ORDER BY custom_calc DESC;
```

Im my problem i have a variable, in this case **{{current_tax}}**. In this way I can not pre calculate the result to do the sorting because the variable can change at any time.

there is an elegant solution to problems like this?

Tanks!

Comment: You can't; the datastore doesn't support this. (Although you can precompute `price * quantity`; surely the value of `current_tax` can't affect the sort order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html), GQL does not support any arithmetic in the SELECT statement.

GQL is there as a convenience for people coming from SQL background, but the low level datastore API is much more like an indexed k/v store.

If `current_tax` is always a positive factor applied on `price * qty` it will not to modify the ordering anyway, so I would recommend storing `price * qty` as a new Product field, `total_price` and create a DESC index for it.

Comment: I think my example was not very good. I will investigate and publish my project on github. This way I can explain the problem.

Comment: My problem is more like this: http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/articles/overheard.html